# Store the values from gridview to string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, gridview

I am storing the value of gridview into a string. I have two lines of code.

```
string UserName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text.ToString(); 1

string UserName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Values["UserName"].ToString(); 2
```

Both will have same Values. Which is the better option to use 1 or 2 ?

Comment: What is `Values` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use the second one, so that if the column index change in time, it's not necessary to rewrite all indexes in code again.

Comment: In terms of Execution Time?

Answer (score 1):

The second one:

1. Its more future proof, changing the structure of the table would
   require you to change the cell index.
2. Its easier to read, without looking at the variable we can see you are asking for the usernames, We don't have to check what values are in the 4th column.